# Novice-Question: is this a 68pol mini SCSI Sub D socket in this controller?

Tags: scsi

I have this SCSI controller LSI20320IE [image][SCSI-Controller](https://www.ebay.de/itm/203347271163?hash=item2f58711dfb:g:PBQAAOSw-HZgEtrw) and would like to know what SCSI cable is the right one. I want to connect a LTO2 with 68 pol female. Is that a 68 pol MINI SUB D SCSI socket ( I have read: *"For Wide SCSI-2, the most common connector was the larger sibling of the MD50, known as the MD68, HD68, MiniD68, or HPDB68. This is about 1 7/8” (47mm) wide. IBM used the HDCN68 on some RS-6000 systems, and it seems likely that a few other manufacturers used other alternatives".* Source: [WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_connector) ) on the controller? Where to get a proper calbe for it? THANKS

Answer (score 1):

According to this Product INFO PAGE [LSI20320IE](https://www.quantelectronic.de/Server-und-Workstation/Zubehoer/SCSI--und-Raidcontroller/HP-SC11Xe-U320-SCSI-Controller-PCIe-x4-LSI20320IE-439946-001-i133_27377.htm) the external connector is a VHDCI SCSI connector. And the cable could be get here: [Gekko-computer](https://www.gekko-computer.de/sonstiges/Kabel-Adapter/SCSI-Kabel/Dell-SCSI-Kabel-VHDCI-M-HD68-M-4m-0FJ114.html)